# What's wrong with my initialization using Eigen?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

i want to initialize a Matrix ,but it is not what I expected.

```
int main()
{
    int N = 84; /
    MatrixXd A(N, N);
    VectorXd b(N);

    // initialization
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        A(i, i) = 6;
        A(i + 1, i) = 8;
        A(i, i + 1) = 1;
        b(i + 1) = 15;
    }
    A(N - 1, N - 1) = 8;
    b(0) = 7;
    b(N - 1) = 14;

    VectorXd x(N);
    std::cout << "A= " << A << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b= " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:
A=-4.83677e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26
-4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26           8           6           1 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26
-4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26 -4.8367e-26
............

vector b is what i expected ,but A do something wrong

i want to konw  why

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/xa3a95nEE. I removed that `/`, assume it is a typo?

Comment: [Cannot repro](https://godbolt.org/z/s1fdYEcor) - diagonal values look ok, the rest uninitialized, as expected.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Did you want the off-diagonal entries to be zero?

Comment: I know what happen. Eigen dont auto initialize A=zeros like C++ std vector does.

Comment: a stupid mistake i make

Comment: If you know the solution please [edit] the shown code into an [mre] (so that theoretically others could also habe found the solution) and ideally according to [answer] - and then you can create your own answering post.